# Conda build fails due to msgpack dependency (issue with old name - msgpack-python)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, msgpack

I'm trying to build a Python `conda` package that depends on a pip library (distributed) which depends on `msgpack`. I keep getting the error that downloading in `setuptools` is disabled, but I have `msgpack` (or `msgpack-python`, i've tried both) listed in my dependencies. I believe this is due to a name change on pip.

old name was `msgpack-python`, new one is `msgpack`.

`distributed` lists `msgpack` as a dependency, but it looks like `conda` installs `msgpack-python` as a conda package (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/msgpack-python). And then it complains that `setuptools` is requiring `msgpack` and it can't download.

Could it be that the name needs to be changed on Anaconda to msgpack?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Searching for msgpack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 41, in <module>
    include_package_data=True
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 117, in do_egg_install
    cmd.run()
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 412, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 654, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 701, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 746, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 770, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1053, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1065, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 661, in easy_install
    not self.always_copy, self.local_index
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 656, in fetch_distribution
    self.find_packages(requirement)
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 489, in find_packages
    self.scan_url(self.index_url + requirement.unsafe_name + '/')
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 829, in scan_url
    self.process_url(url, True)
  File "/Users/bschreck/miniconda3/envs/py3default/conda-bld/featuretools_1530818194289/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 324, in process_url
    "Be sure to add all dependencies in the meta.yaml  url=%s" % url)
RuntimeError: Setuptools downloading is disabled in conda build. Be sure to add all dependencies in the meta.yaml  url=https://pypi.org/simple/msgpack/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by changing the arguments to pip in the build command to this:

`python -m pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed .`

With the key flag being `--no-deps`. I explicitly tell conda to install `msgpack-python` (wa conda package) in the `meta.yaml` file, and then the later pip installation does not check for the `msgpack` dependency (which I assume fails because it only sees `msgpack-python`, not `msgpack`)